# Why does the browser change the value of the option in a <select> element?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a  where the options are generated in php. The some of values include HTML special chars like &amp; or like in this case &Oslash; (danish Ø).

For some reason the browser changes value of the option, making it difficult to compare it to the same value passed to a simple compare function.

With option 1 selected ("&Oslash;strig") and passing "&Oslash;strig" to below countryFilter function, it will return false ??? And deugging it I can see that e.value is equal to "Østrig" and not the value I set it to in the HTML??

HTML:

```
<form>
  <select id='country' onchange='filter(false);'>
    <option value=''>* Alle *</option>
    <option value='&Oslash;strig'>&Oslash;strig</option>
    <option value='Argentina'>Argentina</option>
    <option value='Australien'>Australien</option>
...
```

JavaScript:

```
  function countryFilter(country)
  {
    var e = document.getElementById('country');
    if (e.value=='') return true;
    return e.value.localeCompare(country)==0;
  }
```

It makes sense that the displayed text is translated into & and Ø but the data in the value option should remain untouched.

If I change the options to be added dynamically in JavaScript iso php, then it works again, but then the displayed value is not translated :-/

1) Why does the browser (tested both Chrome and IE) mess with my data?

2) Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem because you probebly used some online English translator. Anyway. Try changing <form> to <form accept-charset="utf-8">.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the content of value-attributes is defined as CDATA(http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-value-OPTION).

For CDATA the [documentation says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata):

> CDATA is a sequence of characters from the document character set and
>   may include character entities. User agents should interpret attribute
>   values as follows:

- **Replace character entities with characters**,
- Ignore line feeds,
- Replace each carriage return or tab with a single space

That's what the browser does, he replaces the entities with characters.

You may e.g. use `Østrig` for the comparison, or when you want to use the string with entities parse the string before the comparision:

```
  function countryFilter(country){
    var e = document.getElementById('country'),
        n = document.createElement('span');
        n.innerHTML=country;
    if (e.value=='') return true;
    return e.value.localeCompare(n.textContent)==0;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. 

Can see it is correct according to the definition. it just doesn't make sens to me that it can change data. 

btw. I solved it by double encoding it in php.... i.e. &amp;Oslash;strig becomes &Oslash;strig